# Как вставить значение, сгенерированное в javascript в input?

Tags: javascript

Есть генератор случайных чисел:

```js
<script language="JavaScript">
var tmp = Math.round((Math.random() * (999999999 - 100000000)));
</script>
```

Выводится переменная полученного значения:

```js
<script>
document.write(tmp);
</script>
```

Как это значение вывести в imput? value="document.write(tmp);" - не работает.
Благодарен за любое помощь!

Answer (score 8):

```
document.getElementById('myInput').value = tmp;
```

Comment: или с использованием JQuery:
$("#InputID").val(tmp);